# grouby parts of signal in pandas dataframe over a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains the following, in a visual form:

[image]

One signal and a set of true or false values associated to it depending on if is over or under a threshold. How could I `groupby` the parts of the signal that are over the threshold in separate groups? For simplicity, let's assume that I have the following data:

```
TESTDATA = StringIO("""date;value;over_th
2023-05-04 10:34:51.002100665;0.4;True
2023-05-04 10:34:51.007100513;0.5;True
2023-05-04 10:34:51.012100235;0.4;True
2023-05-04 10:34:51.017100083;0.3;False
2023-05-04 10:34:51.022099789;0.2;False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.610740595;0.1;False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.615740466;0.7;True
2023-05-04 10:35:23.620740227;0.8;True
2023-05-04 10:35:23.625740082;0.1;False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.630739797;0.7;True
2023-05-04 10:35:23.631;0.2;False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.632;0.8;True
2023-05-04 10:35:23.633;0.1;False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.634;0.9;True
2023-05-04 10:35:23.635;0.2;False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.630739797;0.4;True
    """)
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear if you just want to form the groups or do something with each group. You could create a new column with groupings for the sequences of True values using the approach in SO Answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257319):

```
m = df['over_th']
df['tgroup'] = m[m].groupby((~m).cumsum()).ngroup()
df = df.dropna(axis = 0, subset = ['tgroup'])
df['tgroup'] = df['tgroup'].astype(int)
```

and then create a new index to show the groups

```
df2 = df.set_index('tgroup')
print(df2)

                                 date  value  over_th
tgroup                                               
0       2023-05-04 10:34:51.002100665    0.4     True
0       2023-05-04 10:34:51.007100513    0.5     True
0       2023-05-04 10:34:51.012100235    0.4     True
1       2023-05-04 10:35:23.615740466    0.7     True
1       2023-05-04 10:35:23.620740227    0.8     True
2       2023-05-04 10:35:23.630739797    0.7     True
3             2023-05-04 10:35:23.632    0.8     True
4             2023-05-04 10:35:23.634    0.9     True
5       2023-05-04 10:35:23.630739797    0.4     True
```

or use groupby for some aggregation such as the max value in each group. Please explain if you need some other specific process on each group.

```
df3 = df.groupby('tgroup').max()
print(df3)

tgroup
0    0.5
1    0.8
2    0.7
3    0.8
4    0.9
5    0.4
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @user19077881! Exactly what i was looking for. Btw, for grouping parts of the signal that are under a threshold you can use: `m = ~df['over_th']`

Comment: Actually max was exactly what i wanted to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that somehow assigns group to each value, based on thresholds. And the group by results of function application.

I created a version of `get_group` function with some thresholds, you can choose more appropriate variant:

```
thresholds = [0.1, 0.4, 0.6]

def get_group(value):
    for i, threshold in enumerate(thresholds):
        if value < threshold:
            return i
    return len(thresholds) + 1

df.groupby(df["value"].apply(get_group)).count()
```

Output:

```
       date  value  over_th
value                      
1         7      7        7
2         4      4        4
4         5      5        5
```